# Reading serial data for realtime fft

Tags: python, serial-port, fft

I am writing a python script for a fft in realtime. The code uses arduino as adc converter and reads the value over the serial port. At every step of the while cycle i load the data array and after that i fourier transform it. The problem is that after the first cycle, which takes only 0.01 seconds to buid the array, the other cycles take much longer, 0.98 s. 
Thank you in advance

```
import time
import math
import serial
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import blackman
import numpy as np
t=0
maxLenght=256
stringa=np.zeros(shape=(maxLenght))

seriale=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',57600, timeout=0.1)
time.sleep(3)

cycle=0
while cycle<100:
    print cycle
    cycle+=1
    #seriale.flushInput()
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(0,maxLenght):
        try:
            stringa[i]=seriale.readline()
        except:
            ()
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print elapsed    
            #dati=float(dati)
            #print dati
            #print stringa
    s = time.time()
    T=0.005
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), maxLenght/2)
    w = blackman(maxLenght)
    ywf = fft(stringa*w)
    elapseds = time.time() - s
    print elapseds
    time.sleep(0.5)
    stringa=np.zeros(shape=(maxLenght))
seriale.close()
```